# Swing actionPerformed method

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, actionlistener

I am testing an application that directly implements `ActionListener`

The below application can be compiled and run:

```
public class App implements ActionListener {

JButton button;
int count = 0;

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    App gui = new App();
    gui.go();
}

public void go()
{
    button = new JButton("Click me!");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            count++;
            button.setText("I've been clicked "+count+" times");
        }
    });

}

}
```

But Eclipse wants the

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

method in App class as well. is this because the "go" method may sometimes not be called making `actionPerformed` not called and then against how implementing works?
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: If you're not going to implement the `actionPerformed` method, then you don't need the `implements ActionListener`

Comment: Remove `implements ActionListener` from your App class declaration.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply because of the java rule for implementing an interface. `ActionListener` interface  has `actionPerformed` method in it. So any class implementing this interface need to provide the implementation for `actionPerformed`.

Read more about using ActionListener here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html